# navigation menu - change individual category text color

Tags: menu, navigation

let's say i set my navigation categories as (Clothes, Shoes, Accessories, Help).  In the CSS file i am able to change the color of the text to say RED, this changes the color of all categories (Clothes, Shoes, Accessories, Help) to red.  What i want is Help to be Blue so that it stands out, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento assigns a unique class to each of the top level list item elements. If Help is the 4th category, you can select it with the 'nav-4' class. To change the text color, you can do this:

```
li.nav-4 > a {
    color: blue !important;
}
```